# How do I fix "Expected primary-expression before > token" in an if-else statement?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make this if-else statement make sure that a number is between 0 and 100 before doing anything else with it.

```
if (test1 < 0 || > 100) // I get the error here.
    {
        cout << "This score is good." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << endl << "ERROR: " << test1 << " is not a valid test score.";

        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: `test1 < 0 || test1 > 100`

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
if (test1 > 0 && test1 < 100) (1-99 are = true)
```

-> it needs a boolean result.

Answer (score 0):

Bah, I had to write test1 twice. Also got the operators wrong.

```
if (test1 >= 0 && test1 <= 100) // I get the error here.
    {
        cout << "This score is good." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << endl << "ERROR: " << test1 << " is not a valid test score.";

        return 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two defects. The first one that results in the compiler error is that condition

```
if (test1 < 0 || > 100) // I get the error here.
```

is syntaxically written incorrectly. There shall be

```
if ( test1 < 0 || test  > 100)
```

The second defect that it would be much better if test had unsigned integral type. In this case you could simplify the condition

```
if ( test > 100)
{
    cout << "This score is good." << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << endl << "ERROR: " << test1 << " is not a valid test score.";

    return 1;
}
```

Also are you sure that you do not mean the following?

```
if ( test <= 100)
{
    cout << "This score is good." << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << endl << "ERROR: " << test1 << " is not a valid test score.";

    return 1;
}
```